# I'm getting error 500 with Spin-cli error in spinnaker

Tags: spinnaker

I need to modify a pipeline template in spinnaker. I have already installed spin-cli and configured by oauth. My spinnaker are installed in Kubernetes cluster and I have a loadBalancer to expose gate.

spin-gate-np       LoadBalancer   10.214.14.73    PUBLIC_IP   8084:31452/TCP   10d

But when I try to get the templates, I only get 500.
I put the endpoint in the config file
Endpoint: http://PUBLIC_IP:8084

And Oauth configured with my IDP data.

Why I'm getting 500 when I run spin pipeline-template list

Thanks!

Comment: Check the Gate logs for the stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

As of today, the command `spin pipeline-templates list` throws error `500 Internal Server Error` because of this issue https://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker/issues/6003 which hasnt been resolved yet.
The error shows up for Spin cli ver 1.18.1 etc including latest ver which is 1.22.0 as of today.
However that particular error doesnt show for ver 1.17.3 or 1.20.0

**To use 1.17.3**

1. curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/spinnaker-artifacts/spin/1.17.3/linux/amd64/spin
2. chmod +x spin
3. sudo mv spin /usr/local/bin/spin

If facing issue with 1.17.3 on other commands, you may download other versions and name them and put them in PATH and then use each of those named binaries on a case to case basis like so

```
curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/spinnaker-artifacts/spin/1.17.3/linux/amd64/spin
chmod +x spin
mv spin spin-1.17.3
cp spin-1.17.3 /usr/local/bin/spin-1.17.3
```

```
curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/spinnaker-artifacts/spin/1.22.0/linux/amd64/spin
chmod +x spin
mv spin spin-1.22.0
cp spin-1.22.0 /usr/local/bin/spin-1.22.0
```

```
curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/spinnaker-artifacts/spin/1.20.0/linux/amd64/spin
chmod +x spin
mv spin spin-1.20.0
cp spin-1.20.0 /usr/local/bin/spin-1.20.0
```

**Usage:**

*do echo $PATH and make sure "/usr/local/bin" is in there*

```
spin-1.17.3 pipeline-templates list
spin-1.22.0 spin pipeline-templates save --file <some file here>
etc......
```